# using DAFIF data in ESRI products

Tags: gis, esri

Does anyone have any experience of plotting DAFIF data in ESRI products? are there any DAFIF to shapefile conversion utelities or libraries out there?

Comment: no, didn't try yet as it wasn't obvious if it was needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be possible in ArcGIS 10 using the Defense Mapping extension, [as shown here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//010500000189000000.htm).